# Flask Wtforms FieldList(FormField to populate a SelectField with choices is not appending to form

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am trying to populate a form using a combination of str and lists.  The string fields in the form populate without issue.  However the selectfield in the form appears to only display the last entry given in the list it receives as if it's overwritten the previous contents in the form.

If the list (later converted to tuple) is :
[['one@email.com', 'two@email.com'], ['one@2email.com', 'two@2email.com]]

What gets displayed in the choices throughout the form will be:

one@2email.com
two@2email.com

I've tried various iterations but no luck so far.

```
    class BulkAddFields(Form):
    ip_addr = StringField(label='ip_addr')
    dom_emails = StringField('dom_emails')
    new_emails = SelectField('new_emails', coerce=int)
  
    class BulkAddForm(FlaskForm):
    incidents = FieldList(FormField(BulkAddFields))
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
    
    form = BulkAddForm()
    # i = str, d = str, n=list
    for i, d, n, in data:
        form.ip_addr = i
        form.dom_emails = d
        form.incidents.append_entry(form) 
        email = list(enumerate(n))
        for sub_form in form.incidents:
            sub_form.new_emails.choices = email
```

I've added a picture/link that shows how the string fields are replicated down the page as expected but the selectfield replicates the last item in the list only.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njybX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it from

```
new_emails = SelectField('new_emails', coerce=int)
```

to

```
new_emails = SelectField('new_emails', coerce=str)
```

You should then be able to pass the choices as a list. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help.  I can see that it is adding first the one list of items, but then it is overriding it with the second list. So the second list is what gets populated in each selectfield no matter how many iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that ended up working.  Although I don't like adding a field to the form each time, knowing that the field is going to exist everytime I wanted to include it in the BulkAddFields but couldn't figure out how.

```
class BaseForm(FlaskForm):
    @classmethod
    def append_field(cls, name, field):
        setattr(cls, name, field)
        return cls

class BulkAddFields(BaseForm):
    ip_addr = StringField(label='ip_addr')
    dom_emails = StringField('dom_emails')

class BulkAddForm(BaseForm):
    incidents = FieldList(FormField(BulkAddFields))
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

form = BulkAddForm()
    for i, d, n, in data:
        email = list(enumerate(n))
        bulkfields = BulkAddFields()
        bulkfields = bulkfields.append_field('new_emails',
                SelectField('New Emails', choices=email))
        form.ip_addr = i
        form.dom_emails = d
        
        form.incidents.append_entry(form)
```

[Picture with repeating selectfield for New Emails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ap7A.png)